# replace tabs and line break R

Tags: r, string, text, line-breaks, stringr

I'm cleaning a large text file to read into R. Almost each line is separated by tabs, but a few long quotations also have line breaks. I am using the tabs to separate the document into a dataframe with a speaker column and a comments column, and these line breaks are ruining my formatting because R thinks that each line is a new speaker but then says the speaker is *NA* when it doesn't find a tab. Here's a sample below of what I have:

```
Interviewer: How are you?

Subject: I'm just incredibly frustrated. <br/>
*NA* Really, R is frustrating me. <br/>
*NA* But maybe someone has a solution for me?

Interviewer: Fortunately, I have an answer for you.
```

And here's what I want:

```
Interviewer: How are you?

Subject: I'm just incredibly frustrated. Really, R is frustrating me. But maybe someone has a solution for me?

Interviewer: Fortunately, I have an answer for you.
```

I'm reading the document in this way:

```
atas <- stri_read_lines("ATAS2.txt") %>% str_replace_all("\t", "TABS_TO_BE_DELETED")
```

(I have that random string because R keeps erasing the tabs when I make the text document a data frame, just FYI).

Now, to remove the line breaks, I've tried:

```
atas2 <- gsub("\r?\n|\r", " ", atas)
```

And

```
atas2 <- str_replace_all(atas, "\n" , " ")
```

I also can't just remove all special characters or formatting to solve this. If I DO have to remove all non-alphanumeric characters, I need to preserve the **tabs** (at least long enough to put in some obscure string in their place that I can later split on), **?**, **.**, **[]**, **()**, and **:**.

I want to either have it ignore those line breaks or somehow merge the rows together. The only caution with just telling it to merge with unmatched rows is I have some lines by themselves without any speaker that will need to be in the speaker column with no attribution, such as (but not limited to):

```
(Laughter)

Interview 41

[Inaudible cross-talk]
```

I appreciate any help that you can offer!

Comment: are you trying to read `tab` deliminated data?

Comment: @Onyambu, no, it's not tab deliminated. The transcribing software that we used to record the interviews authomatically tabbed between speaker and their remarks. There are a few cases where people manually transcribed and there aren't tabs, but 90% of the times, tabs space out the document but the document is not tab deliminated per se

Answer (score 0):

You could take a slightly different approach and do something like this.  Note that you usually have to double-escape special characters in R regex (the first one is to escape the backslash).

```
#read in text as a single string
text <- "Interviewer: How are you?
Subject: I'm just incredibly frustrated. 
    Really, R is frustrating me. 
    But maybe someone has a solution for me?
Interviewer: Fortunately, I have an answer for you."

#add `#` markers to separate text before and after speaker followed by colon 
text2 <- str_replace_all(text, "(\\w+?\\:)", "#\\1#")

#split at markers, remove first blank element, and cast as a 2-column data frame
text3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(str_split(text2, "#")[[1]][-1], ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))

#remove line breaks, tabs etc
text3$V2 <- str_replace_all(text3$V2, "[\\r\\n\\t]+", " ")

#remove excessive white space
text3$V2 <- str_trim(str_replace_all(text3$V2, "\\s+", " "))

text3
            V1                                                                                                    V2
1 Interviewer:                                                                                          How are you?
2     Subject: I'm just incredibly frustrated. Really, R is frustrating me. But maybe someone has a solution for me?
3 Interviewer:                                                                Fortunately, I have an answer for you.
```

Answer (score 0):

if the output as to be as the one shown by Andrew Gustar the you can do:

```
read.csv(text=gsub("\\n(?!\\w+:)","",text,perl = T),sep=":",h=F)
           V1                                                                                                     V2
1 Interviewer                                                                                           How are you?
2     Subject  I'm just incredibly frustrated. Really, R is frustrating me. But maybe someone has a solution for me?
3 Interviewer                                                                 Fortunately, I have an answer for you.
```